# Combine frequency lists with awk

Tags: sorting, awk, frequency, uniq

I want to combine two frequency lists and the frequencies should aggregate. I noticed that there are several threads similar to this but I would like to discuss my approach as well, if this is ok?

So here is what I tried to do in cygwin:

I gathered several recommendations I found in the web and ended up with using sort uniq and awk which seemed useful to me. I tried several things but I will show you only the first and the last:

```
sort testcf.txt | uniq -c  | awk '{  print $2 + $3 "\t" $1 }' > testcf-sorted.txt

...

sort testcf.txt | uniq -c  | awk '{  print $2 "\t" $1 }' > testcf-sorted.txt
```

The list loosk like this:

```
foo 1
bar 3
foo 2
fnord 2
foo 1
fnord 2
```

I want to receive:

```
bar 3
fnord 4
foo 4
```

but I get:

first approach:

```
3   1
2   1
2   1
1   2
2   1
```

Last approach:

```
bar 1
fnord   1
fnord   1
foo 2
foo 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use sort and uniq and your input contains "foo 1" twice, then one of them will be lost.  I think you are simply looking for:

```
awk '{a[$1] += $2} END {for( i in a ) print i, a[i]}' testcf.txt
```

Comment: Possibly with a sort afterwards.